# Structure as a parameter of extern function C

Tags: c, function, structure, extern

I have to read a text file using this structure. Also, I have to use external functions. I made the code for file reading and it works in main function.

Text file:

`banana 3 orange 8 music 9`- first character is a blank space*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct file
{
  char name[30];
  char size;
};


int main()
{
   int n=0;
   struct file f[30];
   FILE *files;
   files=fopen("files.txt","r");
   int n=0;
    while (1)
     {
      fgetc(files);
      if(feof(files)) break;
      fscanf(files,"%s %c",&f[n].name,&f[n].size);
      n++;
     }
}
```

But when I try to make this reading using another c file and extern function it's no working.. :(

This is what is written in filereading.c:

```
void fileReading(struct file *f[30], FILE *files)
{
  int n=0;
 while (1)
 {
   fgetc(files);
   if(feof(files)) break;
   fscanf(files,"%s %c",&f[n].name,&f[n].size);
   n++;
 }
}
```

And fileReading.h:

```
void fileReading(struct fisier *, FILE *);
```

And in main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct file
{
  char name[30];
  char size;
};


int main()
{
   int n=0;
   struct file f[30];
   FILE *files;
   files=fopen("files.txt","r");
   fileReading(f[30],files);
}
```

When I compile it, it says:

```
request for member 'name' in something not a structure or union
request for member 'size' in something not a structure or union|
||=== Build finished: 2 errors, 2 warnings (0 minutes, 0 seconds) ===||
```

Can you help me, please? Thank you!

Comment: `void fileReading(struct file *f[30], FILE *files)` --> `void fileReading(struct file f[30], FILE *files)`,  `fileReading(f[30],files);` --> `fileReading(f, files);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I see it looks like you do not have a good understanding of pointers.
These changes should solve your problem:

```
void fileReading(struct file *f, FILE *files)
{
  int n=0;
 while (1)
 {
   fgetc(files);
   if(feof(files)) break;
   fscanf(files,"%s %c",f[n].name,&f[n].size);
   //printf("%s %c",f[n].name,f[n].size);
   n++;
 }
}
int main()
{
   int n=0;
   struct file f[30];
   FILE *files;
   files=fopen("files.txt","r");
   fileReading(f,files);
}
```

What you did wrong:

```
void fileReading(struct file *f[30], FILE *files)  //here you were saying file is a ** 
fscanf(files,"%s %c",&f[n].name,&f[n].size); // here you need to send the a char* but you were sending a char ** as a second parameter
fileReading(f[30],files); // here you were sending the 31th element of the structure array f which by the way doesn't exist (indexing is from 0 , f[29] is the last) even though that was not what you wanted to do in the first place
```

Answer (score 1):

The file fileReading.c doesn't know the definition of `struct file`.  You need to move it from main.c to fileReading.h and `#include "fileReading.h"` in both main.c and fileReading.c.

Also, the definition and call of fileReading is incorrect.  Instead of:

```
void fileReading(struct file *f[30], FILE *files)
```

You want:

```
void fileReading(struct file *f, FILE *files)
```

And you call it like this:

```
fileReading(f,files);
```

This is incorrect:

```
fileReading(f[30],files);
```

Because you're passing a single `struct file` instead of the array, and the single instance you're passing is one element off the end of the array (since the size is 30, valid indexes are 0-29), which can cause indefined behavior.

Comment: When I'm including `fileReading.h` in`main.c` and `fileReading.c` it says this: 

     `fisiere.h: No such file or directory|
     ||=== Build finished: 1 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 0 seconds) ===|`

Comment: @ProgrammingFailure So is you header file called fileReading.h or fisiere.h?  Whatever it's called, make sure that file is in the same directory as the .c files and that the real name of the file is included in both source files.

Comment: @ProgrammingFailure  When posting code, post your *actual* code via copy/paste, not something you typed in separately or made extra edits to.